# simple aws-sdk for nodejs not working

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am trying to have a simple process happen on my S3 account using Amazon's node pluging https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js

Here is my node code:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

AWS.config.update({
    "accessKeyId": "ACCESS_KEY",
    "secretAccessKey": "SECRET",
    "region": "us-west-2"
});

s3.createBucket({Bucket: 'testBucket'});
```

I have a feeling that my issue has more to do with my permissions on S3, but not sure.  The user I am using has an "AmazonS3FullAccess" policy attached to it. Is there something else that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As expected, it was an issue with permissions. The user account i was using was associated to a specific bucket. So creating a new bucket was out of the scope of the permission settings.